# voltage divider using skrf

Tags: voltage-divider, python

I'm trying to use Python skrf's Circuit description and started with a voltage divider but I must be mis-using the library because my attempt does not give a realistic result. The circuit I try to model is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkEEVy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In Python, I use the following code which I thought would create the circuit I want to create:

```
import skrf as rf
rffreq = rf.Frequency(0.01, 10, 101, 'ghz')
media = rf.DefinedGammaZ0(rffreq, z0=50)
resistor1 = media.resistor(50, name='R1')
resistor2 = media.resistor(50, name = 'R2')

portl = rf.Circuit.Port(rffreq, name = 'port_left', z0 = 50)
portr = rf.Circuit.Port(rffreq, name = 'port_right', z0 = 50)
gnd = rf.Circuit.Ground(rffreq, name = 'GND')

connections = [[(portl, 0), (resistor1, 0)],
          [(resistor1, 1),(resistor2, 0), (portr, 0)],
          [(resistor2, 1),(gnd,0)]]
circuit = rf.Circuit(connections)

circuit.network.plot_s_db()
plt.show()
```

Plotting the s-parameter of the network implied by the circuit I would expect a flat response at -6dB, but instead I have one around -8 dB as you can see below. So clearly I am mis-using this tool but what am I misunderstanding and how do I represent the circuit I want? I'd like to use skrf instead of a spice tool because I will use it to model RF circuits (assuming I get responses that make sense out of it).

[image: s_parameter response of the implied network]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You believed that you're simulating this circuit - a voltage divider connected to an ideal voltage source (zero output impedance) at one side, and to an ideal voltmeter (infinite input impedance) at the other side.

[image: Voltage divider]

But you're in fact simulating this circuit - a voltage divider connected to an RF/microwave signal generator (50 Ω output impedance) at one side, and to a matched RF load or test instrument (50 Ω input impedance) at the other side.

[image: Voltage divider, but the signal generator and the output has 50 Ω impedance]

To make it more obvious, you basically created this circuit:

[image: Equivalent circuit of a 50 Ω RF source connected to a 50 Ω load, with a 50-50 voltage divider inserted between them]

If you solve this circuit, you would see that the 8 dB insertion loss is the correct answer.

Recall the definition of insertion loss or |S21| - a 50 Ω load directly connected to a matched 50 Ω generator has a 0 dB insertion loss. In RF circuits, intuitively, |S21| always represents the loss of power undeliveried to the load with respect to the matched condition - this is different from the usual definition of "voltage loss/gain" as seen by a high-impedance voltmeter, which is common in basic linear circuit analysis.

### Insertion Loss Calculation

[image: Equivalent circuit of a 50 Ω RF source connected to a 50 Ω load]

Start from the matched condition: apply a voltage of 1 volt from the generator (before the output resistance), the voltage across the 50 Ω load is 0.5 volt, and the dissipated power is 5 milliwatts - the insertion loss is 0 dB by definition.

[image: Equivalent circuit of a 50 Ω RF source connected to a 50 Ω load, with a 50-50 voltage divider inserted between them]

Then, insert the voltage divider into the circuit, the output resistance is now 100 Ω, which is connected to a 50 Ω resistor to ground, and to another a 50 Ω load to ground. Now, apply a voltage of 1 volt, the voltage across the 50 Ω load is:

$$ \frac{25}{100 + 25} = 0.2\text{ V} $$

And the dissipated power is 0.8 milliwatts.

This is a power reduction of

$$ \log_{10}{(\frac{0.8}{5})} \cdot 10 = -7.958\text{ dB} $$

### Remarks

As you see, `scikit-rf` is specifically designed for solving RF and microwave circuits, so the use of matched source and load at a consistent system impedance is almost always the standard, such as 50 Ω, 75 Ω, 600 Ω, or a custom value. It's how S-parameters are defined.

If you want to see how a correct, matched-impedance RF power divider or attenuator should be designed, check David M. Pozar's *Microwave Engineering*, Chapter 7, *Power Dividers and
Directional Couplers* for details. The pages [*Attenuators*](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/attenuators) and *[Resistive Power Splitters](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/resistive-power-splitters)* from Microwaves101 are also a good introduction. Try designing a proper 6 dB "T-pad" RF attenuator and simulate it using the method shown in these pages.

Alternatively, if you're trying to simulate non-RF problems with zero output impedance and infinite input impedance, scikit-rf simply is not the correct tool for the job. I recommend you to use a SPICE-based simulator, such as [PySpice](https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.5/).

For example, this is how to program a [DC simulation of a voltage divider in PySpice](https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.5/examples/fundamental-laws/voltage-current-divider.html):

```py
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Unit import *

circuit = Circuit('Voltage Divider')

circuit.V('input', 1, circuit.gnd, 1@u_V)
circuit.R(1, 1, 2, 50@u_Ω)
circuit.R(2, 2, circuit.gnd, 50@u_Ω)

simulator = circuit.simulator(
    temperature=25,
    nominal_temperature=25
)
analysis = simulator.operating_point()

for node in analysis.nodes.values():
    print('Node {}: {:5.2f} V'.format(str(node), float(node)))
```

The output is:

```
$ python3 divider.py 
Unsupported Ngspice version 38
Node 2:  0.50 V
Node 1:  1.00 V
```

The "Unsupported Ngspice version 38" warning is usually harmless, it's more of a disclamer. Ngspice 38 is just what happened to be installed on my system.

AC simulations, Bode plots, and transient simulations are also supported. Check the documentation for details.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner and thank you very much for your answer!